# javascript parameter issue while onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to implement toggle of div based on their class name. JavaScript function call gives following error when i pass parameter to function.

```
Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token }
```

**I tried following code its not working .**

but both will work if no parameter is present to function call..Please help.

```
Response.write "<div onclick='toggleDiv('pure-form')'><h3><div id='heading'><center>Successfully Updated!</center></div></h3></div>"

Response.write "<div onclick=""toggleDiv(""pure-form"")""><h3><div id='heading'><center>Successfully Updated!</center></div></h3></div>"
```

**works:**

```
Response.write "<div onclick='toggleDiv()'><h3><div id='heading'><center>Successfully Updated!</center></div></h3></div>"

Response.write "<div onclick=""toggleDiv()""><h3><div id='heading'><center>Successfully Updated!</center></div></h3></div>"

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv(divId) {
alert("hi");
   $("."+divId).toggle();
}
```

Comment: Since the error is client-side, what is the resulting *client-side* markup/code which produces the error?

Comment: why its only giving error when parameter is present?

Comment: The first step toward finding out would be to actually *examine the code*.  Specifically look at the *client-side* code which produces the error, as well as identify specifically *on which line* the error occurs.  You haven't done any of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are doing wrong is the way you call the function. 
Try this instead

onclick="toggleDiv('pure-form')"

using both single and double quotes

Comment: @ kbadas  This is wrong..It wont work..Giving internal server error as ASP/vbscript syntax is wrong..

Comment: Oops, missed the Reponse.Write part. In that case you can write "<div onclick=\"toggleDiv('pure-form')\"><h3><div id='heading'><center>Successfully Updated!</center></div></h3></div>"; using \" so that it will print as double quote html.

Comment: @ kbadas still syntax error of asp.. Mine syntax is write whatever i written in question just when i pass parameter it gives error..please help

Comment: Does your JavaScript code reach the alert part? I tested your code and it seems that the second line (the double quotes one) reaches the alert. The point is what javascript code each one creates. The first one gives <div pure-form')'="" onclick="toggleDiv("> which makes no sense, however the second one gives  onclick="toggleDiv('pure-form')" which should work fine. Isn't it what you get? If not, can you see what is the javascript you create?

Comment: @ kbadas thanks for helping..yes my code reached to alert in both the scenarios..but when i pass "parameter to" `toggleDiv()` it stops and give error.

Comment: Created a <div class="pure-form">Toogle</div> element (similar to the one you have I presume), tested it and toogling seems to be working fine. I'd suggest to try out HTML code directly instead of using Response.Write (using the onclick code on my initial answer). If that doesn't work either try to move the lines of code which give you trouble in a new file with no excess code. Since it works for me, it should work for you too.